# the ideal generated by general polynomials is radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F_1,\dots,F_s$, $s<n$, be homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables of degrees $d_1,\dots,d_s$. 
Let $X$ be the intersection of the $s$ hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined
by $F_1,\dots,F_s$. By the homogeneous Hilbert's nullstellensatz, we know that 
$I_X = \operatorname{rad}(F_1,\dots,F_s)$. However, when $F_1,\dots,F_s$ are general, we have the remarkable fact that $(F_1,\dots,F_s)$ is radical. Can anyone please provide a proof (or sketch of proof) of this fact?

**Edit/Definition:** Recall that the space of polynomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables is parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^{M_n}, M_n:={n+d \choose d}-1$. Then requiring $F_1,\dots,F_s$ to be general for the statement to hold, is interpreted as "there exists a Zariski open set $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^{M_{n_1}} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{P}^{M_{n_s}}$, such that the statement is true for every $s$-tuple of polynomials inside $U$".

**PS:** Since the relation between an ideal and its radical is in general a complicated one, i find the statement of the question extremely interesting and useful and i don't know why finding a proof in the literature seems so hard.

Comment: Easier to prove that this intersection is smooth (and hence reduced) and is known as Bertinii's theorem. A proof can be found in many books.

Comment: I assume that you are interested in the cone, not the ideal sheaf of $X$, which is clearly reduced, since it it smooth. The cone too is reduced by standard facts in algebra, since $F_1,\ldots,F_s$ is a regular sequence. In such a situation, `generic' reducedness implies reducedness.

Comment: This is an easy consequence of `general'. Notice that Bertini says not only that $X$ is smooth, but also of codimension $s$ in the projective space. This can be easily seen to show that the $F_i$s form a regular sequence.

Comment: @Manos Correct, if $R$ is a local ring.

Comment: No! You still need reducedness generically, that is where the projective scheme is smooth (at least reduced) is used.

Comment: The correct (and useful) fact is if $R$ is a regular local ring and $A$ a quotient by by a regular sequence and $A$ localized at the minimal primes is reduced, then so is $A$.

Comment: Minimal primes are not enough. You need associated primes, which may not all be minimal. For example, take $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$. It has only one minimal prime $xA$ and when you localize at this, you get a field. But, $A$ is not reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recall a basic version of Bertini's theorem:

**Theorem (Bertini):** Let $Y$ be any nonsingular, irreducible projective variety; then its intersection $Y \cap H$ with a general hyperplane $H$ will be nonsingular.

Now, suppose that we have $s \le n$ homogeneous polynomials $F_1,\dots,F_s$ of degrees $d_1,\dots,d_s$ in $n+1$ variables. Iterative application of the above theorem on the irreducible components of $Z(F_1,\dots,F_i)$ gives:

**Corollary:** If $F_1,\dots,F_s$ are general, then $X=Z(F_1,\dots,F_s)$ will be nonsingular.

By arguments involving the Hilbert function of $R = S/I, \, I=(F_1,\dots,F_s)$, one can show that

**Proposition:** If $F_1,\dots,F_s$ are general, then $F_1,\dots,F_s$ is a regular sequence.

Note that the above proposition implies that $\operatorname{height}(I)=s$.

Next, let $J$ be the Jacobian ideal of $F_1,\dots,F_s$, i.e. the ideal generated by all $s \times s$ minors of the Jacobian matrix $\left[\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} \right]$. Since $X$ is nonsingular, $J \not\subset \mathfrak{m}_x, \, \forall x \in X$. This means that in the quotient ring $R = S/I$, we must have 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{height}(\bar{J}) = \operatorname{height}(\bar{\mathfrak{m}})=\operatorname{height}(\mathfrak{m})- \operatorname{height}(I) = n+1 -s \ge 1,\end{align}
where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the irrelevant ideal.

Finally, the key to deducing that $I$ is reduced is Serre's criterion for primality, e.g. Theorem 18.15 from Eisenbud, CA, 2004; a quite non-trivial result. According to that Theorem, if $R$ is Cohen Macaulay (and it is in our case since the $F_i$ form a regular sequence), then $I$ is reduced if and only if $\operatorname{height}(\bar{J}) \ge 1$.