# using smoothness to deduce reducedness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F_1,\dots,F_s$ be homogeneous polynomials in the ring $S=k[X_0,\dots,X_n], s < n$ and suppose that they form a regular sequence. Suppose also that $X = V(F_1) \cap \dots \cap V(F_s)$ is smooth. How can the smoothness of $X$ be used to deduce that $(F_1,\dots,F_n)$ is radical or equivalently that $k[X_0,\dots,X_n]/(F_1,\dots,F_s)$ is reduced? In classic terms, smoothness of $X$ is equivalent to $O_{X,P}$ being regular for every point $P \in X$. The issue is that $O_{X,P}$ is related to the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$ rather than $k[X_0,\dots,X_n]/(F_1,\dots,F_s)$.

**PS:** This is the missing step to my understanding of [the ideal generated by general polynomials is radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464774/the-ideal-generated-by-general-polynomials-is-radical).

Comment: Are you assuming that the polynomials are general as in your earlier question? If so, it has been answered there. If they are not general (or at least form a regular sequence), are you sure the statement is true?

Comment: @Mohan: When you say it has been answered there, you refer to your comments?

Comment: Yes, others also might have made similar comments.

Answer (score 1):

Manos, I know the frustration, so let me make another attempt in a different direction. I will do a simple case, where $n=3,s=2$. So, we have $V(F_1,F_2)=X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$, a smooth, irreducible complete intersection curve. Let $I\subset\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}$ be its ideal sheaf. Then, we have the Koszul resolution, $0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-\deg F_1-\deg F_2)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-\deg F_1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-deg F_2)\to I\to 0$, which by using the the fact that $H^i(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(l))=0$ for $i=1,2$ and all $l$ gives $H^1(I(l))=0$ for all $l$ and the map $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-\deg F_1+l)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-\deg F_2+l))\to I(l)$ is onto for all $l$. Thus, we see that $\oplus I(l)\subset\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(l)=k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is just the ideal $(F_1,F_2)$. From the long exact sequence coming from $0\to I\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to 0$, using the vanishing of $H^1$, we get an exact sequence, $0\to (F_1,F_2)\to k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]\to \oplus H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(l))\to 0$. Using the fact that $X$ is integral, easy to check that so is $\oplus H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(l))$, but this is precisely $k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]/(F_1,F_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we can take $s \le n$. Since $F_1,\dots,F_s$ is a regular sequence, we have that $\operatorname{height}(I)=s$, where $I=(F_1,\dots,F_s)$, and also $R=S/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Let $J$ be the Jacobian ideal of $F_1,\dots,F_s$, i.e. the ideal generated by all $s \times s$ minors of the Jacobian matrix of the $F_i$. If $X = Z(F_1,\dots,F_s)$ is smooth, then $J \not\subset \mathfrak{m}_x, \, \forall x \in X$ and so in the quotient ring $R$ we must have $\operatorname{height}(\bar{J}) \ge 1$. Finally, according to Theorem 18.15a in Eisenbud (CA, 2004) $I$ is reduced if and only if $\operatorname{height}(\bar{J}) \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F_1,\ldots,F_s$ are general, by Bertini theorem, we get that $\dim X=n-s$ and it is smooth. Thus, $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/(F_1,\ldots,F_s)$ is a complete intersection (follows from $\dim X=n-s$) and outside the irrelevant  maximal ideal, this ring is regular. Since complete intersection implies the ring is Cohen-Macaulay, to see whether it is reduced, it suffices to do so at the minimal primes and this follows from the regularity at all the relevant primes.

Comment: Actually, the localizations at ALL primes of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ other than the irrelevant maximal ideal are regular, not just homogeneous primes, though it is not so relevant here. As you said, if you have a CM ring, which is reduced at all minimal primes, then it is reduced. Here the minimal primes are not equal to the irrelevant prime and thus localization is regular and thus reduced. CM follows from complete intersection and regularity at minimal primes follows from smoothness of $X$.

Comment: Why don't you just use Jacobian criterion? The Jacobian has maximal rank at every point on $X$ and since these are homogneous polynomials, it follows that the same is true at EVERY point except at the `origin'.

Comment: Use homogeneity. If the rank is small at a point, then it will be small at $\lambda$ times the point for any $\lambda\neq 0$. I think, I have done with explaining. Please work it out in small dimensions, for example a hypersurface.